# jupyter lab importing modules

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I am using jupyter lab on linux, and I have started it various working directories, including `/`, but I am having problems importing a module I installed with pip.

Here is what I did:

`pip install primer3-py`

Then run `ipython`

Within ipython run `import primer3` works as expected where `primer3.calcTm('GTAAAACGACGGCCAGT')` returns `49.16808228911765`

However, if I run `jupyter lab`
Open a console and run `import primer3` I now get an import error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-1493f16bb490> in <module>()
----> 1 import primer3

ImportError: No module named primer3
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: was jupyterlab installed with pip as well? maybe check sys.executable on ipython and jupyterlab to check they are running the same

Comment: no jupyterlab was installed through anaconda, will this cause a problem.

Comment: maybe they are using different interpreters like virtual/conda environments check the sys.executable value on each.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have Anaconda installed have you tried installing `primer3` with `conda`?

Try the following as described [here](https://anaconda.org/bioconda/primer3-py)

```
conda install -c bioconda primer3-py
```

Your Linux installation may have more than one Python distribution installed in addition to your Anaconda installation.  I use Anaconda for my personal Python needs so I don't overlap with the OS's needs.  If there is a package on PyPI which is not on Anaconda Cloud then you can install it with the copy of `pip` which comes with your Anaconda installation.